# CrunchBang & Openbox: no reaction to laptop power button pressed

Tags: linux, debian, openbox, input, crunchbang

I've just installed [#!](http://crunchbang.com/) and I'm loving the customizable Openbox DE.

However, when I press the power button on my laptop, the system doesn't react.

For example, when I was using Debian & Gnome, and when I pressed the said button, Gnome displayed a dialog box asking me whether I want to shutdown etc.

The mentioned dialog box also appears when I go to `menu->exit` in Openbox.

Question: How can I bind the shutdown button to `Openbox->exit`?

Some info:

`xev` + shutdown button says:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) and it works now.

Go to Settings > Power Manager and set those options to "Ask" or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the oblogout application?
https://launchpad.net/oblogout

Comment: I resolved the dependencies but there are still errors in the program... I'd prefer something that works natively, not a third-party program.